# Visual Studio Code no indented code flutter when press Enter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, indentation

I am working with flutter in vscode and when I press enter the cursor is not indented correctly, I currently have the extensions installed from flutter, dart, awesome flutter snippets.
The weird thing is that it doesn't work on a macbook but on my windows computer it works correctly and I have the same extensions installed.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your settings - editor - autoIndent and set it to full.

[image]